# FFT image clearing

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am using python and I need to implement a function to clear a pattern noise from images, I write this function and I get an OK result on some images but on others, I get a bad result, can U guys help me to improve the code?
I can't use cv2, just 'numpy' and 'from scipy.signal import convolve'

```
def fft_clean(img1: np.array, img2: np.array, img3: np.array, img4: np.array) \
    -> (np.array, np.array, np.array, np.array):
    '''
    This function receives 4 grayscale images and clean them using FFT algorithm.

    Args:
        img1:   image array in float format (range: 0..1) - the source grayscale 
                image.
        img2:   image array in float format (range: 0..1) - the source grayscale 
                image.
        img3:   image array in float format (range: 0..1) - the source grayscale 
                image.
        img4:   image array in float format (range: 0..1) - the source grayscale 
                image.

    Returns:
        img_c1:    array in int format (values: 0, 1) - the cleaned image.
        img_c2:    array in int format (values: 0, 1) - the cleaned image.
        img_c3:    array in int format (values: 0, 1) - the cleaned image.
        img_c4:    array in int format (values: 0, 1) - the cleaned image.
    '''
    ######################################################################
    # TODO: Implement The fft algorithm.
    ######################################################################
    def clean(img):
        # perform FFT on the input image
        f = fft2(img)
        # shift the FFT result to center the image
        f = fftshift(f)
        # get the magnitude of the FFT result
        mag = np.abs(f)
        # find the maximum magnitude value
        max_val = np.max(mag)
        # set a threshold that eliminates most of the noise and leaves the line patterns
        threshold = max_val * 0.1
        # create a binary mask with the same size as the image
        mask = np.zeros_like(mag)
        # set the values in the mask corresponding to the line patterns to 1
        mask[np.where(mag < threshold)] = 1
        # apply the mask to the FFT result
        f *= mask
        # shift the result back to its original position
        f = ifftshift(f)
        # perform the inverse FFT to obtain the cleaned image
        img_c = ifft2(f)
        return img_c
    # clean each of the input images and store the result
    img_c1 = clean(img1)
    img_c2 = clean(img2)
    img_c3 = clean(img3)
    img_c4 = clean(img4)
    ######################################################################
    #                            END OF YOUR CODE                        #
    ######################################################################
    return img_c1.real, img_c2.real, img_c3.real, img_c4.real
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

as u can see img1 have washed colors, img2 is great, img3 is ok but the color is little bit washed, and img4  look terrible

https://github.com/dnevo/ImageProcessing/tree/main/images

fft1 - ff4.tiff

---

I change the clean function to this:

```
    def clean(img):
        # perform FFT on the input image
        f = fft2(img)
        # shift the FFT result to center the image
        f = fftshift(f)
        # get the magnitude of the FFT result
        mag = np.abs(f)
        # find the maximum magnitude value
        max_val = np.max(mag)
        # set a threshold that eliminates most of the noise and leaves the line patterns
        threshold = max_val * 0.094
        # create a binary mask with the same size as the image
        mask = np.zeros_like(mag)
        # set the values in the mask corresponding to the line patterns to 1
        mask[np.where(mag < threshold)] = 1
        # apply the mask to the FFT result
        f *= mask
        # shift the result back to its original position
        f = ifftshift(f)
        # perform the inverse FFT to obtain the cleaned image
        img_c = ifft2(f)
        return img_c
```

I just change this line

> threshold = max_val * 0.094

instead of 0.1, I set 0.094 and the last pic is ok now [image]
but the first is still washed.
I also try to change to this:

```
    def clean(img):
        # perform FFT on the input image
        f = fft2(img)
        # shift the FFT result to center the image
        f = fftshift(f)
        # get the magnitude of the FFT result
        mag = np.abs(f)
        # set a threshold that eliminates most of the noise and leaves the line patterns
        threshold = np.max(mag) * 0.094
        # create a binary mask with the same size as the image
        mask = np.zeros_like(mag)
        # set the values in the mask corresponding to the line patterns to 1
        mask[np.where(mag < threshold)] = 1
        # find the coordinates of the peaks in the magnitude spectrum that are above the threshold
        peaks = np.array(np.where(mag > threshold)).T
        # remove the significant peaks that are not at the origin by setting their values in the mask to 0
        for peak in peaks:
            if peak[0] != mag.shape[0]//2 or peak[1] != mag.shape[1]//2:
                mask[peak[0], peak[1]] = 0
        # apply the mask to the FFT result
        f *= mask
        # shift the result back to its original position
        f = ifftshift(f)
        # perform the inverse FFT to obtain the cleaned image
        img_c = ifft2(f)
        return img_c
```

like @CrisLuengo suggest but I get the same results

please let me know where I can improve the code and get better results.

thanks!!

Comment: Would it be possible to share the images somehow, so we can play around with it?

Comment: https://github.com/dnevo/ImageProcessing/tree/main/images

fft1 - ff4.tiff

Comment: Your “cleaning” also removes the zero-order component and the very low frequencies (most likely), which is probably not what you want. Instead, try doing a peak detection, and remove the significant peaks that are not at the origin.

Comment: @RoySmart I update with a link to the imgs

Comment: @CrisLuengo
i change def clean to this:
def clean(img):
    # perform FFT on the input image
    f = fft2(img)
    f = fftshift(f)
    mag = np.abs(f)
    threshold = np.max(mag) * 0.1
    mask = np.zeros_like(mag)
    mask[np.where(mag < threshold)] = 1
    peaks = np.array(np.where(mag > threshold)).T
    for peak in peaks:
        if peak[0] != mag.shape[0]//2 or peak[1] != mag.shape[1]//2:
            mask[peak[0], peak[1]] = 0
    f *= mask
    f = ifftshift(f)
    img_c = ifft2(f)
    return img_c

and still not working